# From finite union to infinite union

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

Given a possibly infinite set $S$ which is closed under the union of two members, ie $x,y\in S\implies x\cup y\in S$, how can I show $S$ is closed under the union of all elements, ie $\bigcup S\in S$?

I can certainly use induction to proof $x_1,\ldots x_n\in S\implies x_1\cup\ldots\cup x_n\in S$ for all $n$ but this doesn't cover the infinite case.

Comment: So $\;S\;$ is in fact a set of sets?

Comment: Yes! The setting is ZF set theory, so everything shall be a set.

Comment: I believe that if S is countable, it sufices to show the result inductively

Comment: @AndresMejia. No it doesn't.

Comment: @TomCollinge thank you, could you give me a reference to read?

Comment: @AndresMejia I like Paul Halmos's Naive Set Theory. It defines induction well, and also, "transfinite induction" which does extend to (various sizes of) infinity. I must warn though that while the first part of the book is easy going, when it gets to TFI you'll need to spend some serious time on it (as you would with any text on this aspect). Good luck.

Comment: You can't show that: It isn't true! (in general)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it true ?

Take $N$ the set of natural numbers.

Let $X$ be the set of all finite subsets of $N$.

I think this is a counterexample.

(P.S. in general, you can't "prove infinity by induction" you can prove by induction that for all **finite** $n$ their union is an element, but that's all).